# Does the Multiplayer Asari shockwave deal as much damage as a normal Heavy Melee?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I got the Asari Vanguard character in Mass Effect 3 multiplayer, and I'm finding her strong melee-a Biotic shockwave-a bit tricky to use, compared to the old fashioned Biotic Punch.

**Does the Asari Biotic Shockwave deal the same damage when close up?** Is the damage fall off particularly sharp?

I can still kill enemies with it, but I can't seem to one-hit kill normal enemies with it with the same ease I can with my Human Vanguard. Am I not getting close enough or does the attack simply deal less damage?

Comment: As a side note, the Biotic Punch is much trickier to aim and needs to lock on, so I think there might be fair reason for it to deal more damage. I'm just wondering if there are actual numbers/facts out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have the numbers in front of me right now, but it does do less damage with it being an area effect. The main purpose for it is not really kill a person, but knock multiple enemies down for you to escape and then kill from cover.

You can choose to have lower health & shields for increased melee damage. I believe if you do your skills this way you can kill the basic enemies.

I looked at the numbers last night, the base damage for the Asari Heavy melee is 650, the base damage for a Krogan Heavy melee is 850, and the base damage for Human Heavy melee is 725.